# What password encryption Hudson is using?

Tags: java, hudson, sha1

This is what I see in `hudson/users/me/config.xml`:

```
[...]
<hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm_-Details>
  <passwordHash>mEDUyJ:0c9e6f2556b9b3a0b9e9046c21490422b4a54877f057b527b2c0bd4dc83342d5</passwordHash>
</hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm_-Details>
[...]
```

What is the algorithm (if SHA1, than what is the `mEDUyJ` prefix)? How can I get this hash in PHP, for example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The source code responsible for this is found in the [`hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm`](https://svn.java.net/svn/hudson~svn/trunk/hudson/main/core/src/main/java/hudson/security/HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm.java) class (more specifically, the `PasswordEncoder` inner class).

Consider your example:

```
mEDUyJ:0c9e6f2556b9b3a0b9e9046c21490422b4a54877f057b527b2c0bd4dc83342d5
```

The prefix (`mEDUyJ`) is actually a six-letter salt. A salt can be any six-letter permutation of uppercase letters and lowercase letters.

Hudson uses the [Acegi Security library](http://www.acegisecurity.org/). More specifically, it uses that library's [`ShaPasswordEncoder`](http://www.acegisecurity.org/acegi-security/apidocs/org/acegisecurity/providers/encoding/ShaPasswordEncoder.html) class. It's basically doing this:

```
String salt = generateSomeSixLetterSalt() // Fictional function
String passwordHash = salt + ":" + new ShaPasswordEncoder(256).encodePassword(password, salt);
```

Once you view the source code for `ShaPasswordEncoder`, you find this it's essentially doing this:

```
// Fictional functions ahead...
String salt = generateSomeSixLetterSalt()
String passwordHash = salt + ":" + hex_encode(sha256_hash(utf8_encode(password + "{" + salt + "}")))
```

Comment: The link is now dead: _We're sorry the java.net site has closed._