# How to correctly encode password using ShaPasswordEncoder?

Tags: java, spring, hash, spring-security, sha

I want to encode a password using `ShaPasswordEncoder` in my **Spring** app.

```
ShaPasswordEncoder sha = new ShaPasswordEncoder(256);
sha.setIterations(1000);
String hash = sha.encodePassword(password, salt);
```

But I don't what I should put to `salt param`. Can it be a static phrase (e.g. *sT4t1cPhr453*), or dynamic string different for every user (e.g. username or user ID)?

### Edit:

I user custom `AuthenticationProvider`, so my security context looks like:

```
<authentication-manager>
   <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="com.app.cloud.auth.CustomAuthenticationProvider">

@Component("customAuthenticationProvider")
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private AuthService authService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException,BadCredentialsException {
    //...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hashing password using sha256 may not be secure enough.
You may have a look at [this](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#javasourcecode). It provides a secure password hashing (Java PBKDF2 Password Hashing) with source code.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean to use Spring security context? Because I'm using custom `AuthenticationProvider`, so I don't know add password encoder to my security context.

Comment: If you use the password hashing class in the above website. You can use custom AuthenticationProvider in Spring Security like this:
 <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userAuthenticationService">
   <password-encoder ref="pbkdf2PasswordEncoder" />
  </authentication-provider>
 </authentication-manager>

Comment: And you need to define your bean in you application context:
<bean id="pbkdf2PasswordEncoder" class="com.example.PBKDF2PasswordEncoder"/>

Comment: @WilliamLAM - A salted hash with SHA256 and 1000 iterations is absolutely fine. What makes you think it may not be secure enough?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In case you want to explicitly define the salt you can define the salt source:

**Dynamic salt (based on the username property)**

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="sha-256">
            <salt-source user-property="username"/>
        </password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

**Static salt**

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="sha-256">
            <salt-source system-wide="MySalt" />
        </password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

**Recommended approach**

If you are using Spring Security 3.1, the recommended approach would be to go for bcrypt, this automatically generates a salt and concatenates it.

```
<beans:bean id='bCryptPasswordEncoder' class='org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder'/>

<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
          <password-encoder ref="bCryptPasswordEncoder"/>
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

You can generate the user password like this:

```
String password = "p4ssword";
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
```

Comment: I'm using custom AuthenticationProvider, so my authentication-provider looks `<authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider"><password-encoder ref="bCryptPasswordEncoder"/></authentication-provider>`, but here is conf. problem - `authentication-provider element cannot have child elements when used with 'ref' attribute`

Comment: Add it to your AuthenticationProvider: <bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
  <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
  <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="bCryptPasswordEncoder" />
</bean>

Comment: I added details around my AuthProvider, please look at the edit. There are some dissimilarities, that obstruct the correct configuration.

Comment: Perfect! It works, I mistake `name attr` with `id attr` in the configuration.

Comment: I'm using Bcrypt but it not working. Alway invalid username password. I use BCryptPasswordEncoder to hash the password. And using BCrypt.checkpw for compare password

Answer (score 2):

The principle behind salting hashes is that you are not vulnerable to rainbow tables. If you use static salt then its possible (but expensive) for someone to build a rainbow table for *your* salt. If the pickings are sweet, someone will do it.

Ideally your salt should be random (eg use bytes from a `SecureRandom`) and should be different for each user. You should store the salt alongside the hashed password, eg if you are using a database table then simply have a salt column.

The latest versions of Spring Security (3.1 and later) try to handle salt in an automatic, transparent manner. The password encoder will automatically generate random salt and append it to the hash instead of storing it separately (eg in different columns). Because hashes and the salt have a fixed length it is easy to determine which part of the data is which.

Comment: Is Hudson encryption the correct way? e.g. this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358146/what-password-encryption-hudson-is-using/4358406#4358406